# how to detect the tag ofimage subviews when i touched the image in the rotatory uiview

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I want to create a dial and i want to get the tag of images when clicked the images in the dial.i tried a lot , but i didn't get it.see the code below

```
- (void) drawWheel {

container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];

CGFloat angleSize = 2*M_PI/numberOfSections;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSections; i++) {

    UIImageView *im = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"segment.png"]];

    im.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0f, 0.5f);
    im.layer.position = CGPointMake(container.bounds.size.width/2.0-container.frame.origin.x, 
                                    container.bounds.size.height/2.0-container.frame.origin.y); 
    im.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleSize*i);
    im.alpha = minAlphavalue;
    im.tag = i;

    if (i == 0) {
        im.alpha = maxAlphavalue;
    }

    cloveImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 15, 40, 40)];
    cloveImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"icon%i.png", i]];
    cloveImage.tag=i;
   [im addSubview:cloveImage];
```

}

```
    -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

{

//i want to get cloveImage.tag when i clicked the imageview

}

So my question is how can I detect tag of image in the rotatory wheels when i touched the
particular image?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you add buttons instead on UIImageView and then add background image to the uibuttons.As far as getting the tag is concerned you shall get the corresponding tag of clicked buuton in its target method

Answer (score 0):

```
for (UIImageView *img in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if ([img isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
        {
            if (img.tag==index)
            {
                Your code....
            }
        }

    }
```

You use the above code for getting tha tag of Perticular image by using for loop..

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
... ...
cloveImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 15, 40, 40)];
cloveImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"icon%i.png", i]];
cloveImage.tag=i;
//   **********add begin**********
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showCloveImageTagOnImageView:)];
[cloveImage addGestureRecognizer:tapGR];
//   **********add end**********
[im addSubview:cloveImage];
... ...



//  copy the selector below and log the cloveImageTag
- (void)showCloveImageTagOnImageView: (UIImageView *)tappedImageView
{
    NSLog(@"tappedImageView.tag: %d", tappedImageView.tag);
}
```